# Regex check if from one string to other string contains seaching string

Tags: regex, search, regex-group

I need a regex expression that searches a string inside regex selection. For example i have this text

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the **printing** and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a **galley** of type and
> scrambled it to make a type specimen **book**. It has survived not only
> five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
> remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
> the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
> more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
> including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

and i need to check if from string **printing** to string **book** there is a string **galley**

Comment: something like `/\b(printing)\b[^\3]*?\b(galley)\b[^\3]*?\b(book)\b/` ? you can compose it via `RegExp` constructor too

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was searching for. You can post it as "Answer" so i can accept it @AndreaGiammarchi

Comment: `(printing.*(galley))(?=.*book)` select second group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(printing.*(galley))(?=.*book)` select second group